# Equality of multiplicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I am struggling with the following definition/exercise.
The definition of multiplicity is given to us as follow. Let $f\in k[x,y]$ and $p = (a,b)\in \mathbb A^2(k)$, write $f= f_0+\dots +f_{\deg f}$ with
$$f_i =\sum_{\alpha +\beta =i} \lambda_{\alpha,\beta}(x-a)^\alpha (y-b)^\beta.$$
The multiplicity of $f$ in $p$ is defined as $$m_p(f) := \min \{i: f_i\neq 0\}.$$

After this definition we got the following exercise to solve. Let $\psi:\mathbb A^2(k)\to \mathbb A^2(k)$ be a coordinate change where the components are linear terms with as constant terms (a,b). Let $P=(0,0)$ and let $f\in k[x,y]$ be a non constant polynomial. Prove that
$$m_P(f\circ \psi) = m_{\psi(P)}(f).$$

My attempt to it: (let $d=\deg (f)$)
Write $f= \sum_{i=1}^d f_i$ with $f_i = \sum_{\alpha+\beta =i} \lambda_{\alpha,\beta}x^\alpha y^\beta$, then
$$f\circ \psi = \sum_{i=1}^d f_i\circ \psi\quad f_i\circ\psi = \sum f_i = \sum_{\alpha+\beta =i} \lambda_{\alpha,\beta}(cx+dy+a)^\alpha (ex+gy+b)^\beta.$$
From this point on I don't know how to manipulate this expression to get the desired result by definition.

Can someone help me please, I would also like some intuition behind this multiplicity concept. It feels like my polynomial is changing when we change the point we are interested in, however this should not be the case since it is invariant under a change of coordinates.

Comment: Write $\psi$ as $\psi_2 \circ \psi_1$ where $\psi_1(x, y) = (cx + dy, ex + gy)$ and $\psi_2(x, y) = (x + a, y + b)$. Now it is enough to prove the statement for $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ individually.

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving an answer. That's against the rules around here.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the computation. If $P=(0,0)$ and the transformation is $(x,y)\mapsto (cx+dy+a,ex+gy+b)$ then $\psi(P)=(a,b)$, so letting

$$f_i =\sum_{\alpha +\beta =i} \lambda_{\alpha,\beta}(x-a)^\alpha (y-b)^\beta$$

and substituting $(x,y)\mapsto (cx+dy+a,ex+gy+b)$ gives

$$f_i\circ\psi =\sum_{\alpha +\beta =i} \lambda_{\alpha,\beta}(cx+dy+a-a)^\alpha (ex+gy+b-b)^\beta$$
$$f_i\circ\psi =\sum_{\alpha +\beta =i} \lambda_{\alpha,\beta}(cx+dy)^\alpha (ex+gy)^\beta$$

then expanding and recollecting, $$f_i\circ\psi = \sum_{\gamma+\delta=i} \lambda'_{\gamma,\delta}x^\gamma y^\delta.$$

The point is that multiplicity is independent of linear coordinate changes.